# Haproxy service won’t start when keepalived service is running

Tags: centos, haproxy, keepalived

I am trying to configure haproxy with keepalived but if I start keepalived service first, haproxy fails to start. When keepalived service is stopped, haproxy starts without any problems. I get the error below when I attempt to start haproxy manually while keepalived is running:
Proxy ‘webserver’: unable to find local peer ‘VIP01.domain.com’ in peers section ‘mypeer’.
Fatal errors found in configuration.
Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Failed with result ‘exit-code’.
Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.

The system is Centos 8 and I found the article below and checked if net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind sysctl is set to 1 but it still doesn’t start when keepalived is running.
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/management.html#11

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the output of ``sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c`` command?

Comment: This is the output: Proxy ‘webserver’: unable to find local peer ‘VIP01.domain.com’ in peers section ‘mypeer’. Fatal errors found in configuration. Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Failed with result ‘exit-code’. Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.

Comment: but if I stop keepalived service, the output is this: Configuration file is valid